# Why does the order of the element I'm defining in my .css file affect how it appears when rendered?

Tags: html, css

(See update below)

I have two files: a .css file, and an index.html document. The idea is to have a panel of buttons on the screen [for prototyping usability of a touchscreen interface] with each button assigned a particular position on screen (see the "margin-top" and "margin-left" tags in the .css file. Later on I'll be adding onclick functionality etc.

For now though, I am trying just to get them to display correctly on the screen.
What's strange, is that the first element in the .css part (ie. the .aButton #....) is always displayed up at position (0,0) when displayed in the browser. eg. at the moment, button1 will be up at (0,0) but all the other buttons are in the correct places. 
If I change the css code, and move the button2 section up above the button1 section, then button1 is rendered in the correct place, but button2 is now at (0,0).

Would be very grateful for any ideas!

Here are the relevant parts:
from index.html

```
<div id="buttonPanel" class="aButton">
            <div id="button1" class="aButton"></div>
            <div id="button2" class="aButton"></div>            
            <div id="button3" class="aButton"></div> 
            <div id="button4" class="aButton"></div>
            <div id="button5" class="aButton"></div>
</div>
```

from styles.css:

```
.aButton #button1
{
    margin-top: 262px;
    margin-left: 110px;
}

.aButton #button2
{
    margin-top: 24px;
    margin-left: 347px;
}

.aButton #button3
{
    margin-top: 32px;
    margin-left: 114px;
}

.aButton #button4
{
    margin-top: 524px;
    margin-left: 104px;
}
.aButton #button5
{
    margin-top: 392px;
    margin-left: 106px;
}
```

**Update:** Have updated Fr0zenFyr's jsfiddle with the whole html and css files and get an identical problem! http://jsfiddle.net/b4NYd/
It was silly of me not to include them both before, as I now suspect it's got something to do with the .aButton #buttonx {} definitions interacting strangely with the #buttonx {} definitions beforehand.
I can manage to make the problem go away by merging the two, but I really would like to understand why this kind of problem occurs, as I'd like to use different classes later when prototyping different layouts.

**Update:** All sorted! It was my comments, argh!

Comment: Looks fine to me: http://jsfiddle.net/Tdvev/

Comment: Hi Fr0zenFyr, thanks for the jsfiddle - I've updated it with my complete code and am still getting the same problem, as per the Update above.

Comment: @Nathan look at my updated solution

Comment: Glad that issue is resolved now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is your comments. that's not how comments are written in css. 
you need to use `/*` notation.

do this

```
 /* interface 1 */
 /* need to change all of these according to what numbers I've got in my logbook.*/
```

Comment: Thanks btevfik - I've been coding a lot of C++ recently so I forget the obvious things sometimes!!!

Comment: yeah it gives me headaches sometimes too. html, css and js have all different type of commenting

Comment: can you select this as the answer? @Nathan

Answer (score 1):

Moving the order of the CSS, in your case, should not affect the output of your HTML elements.  You can reverse the order of all css classes for your buttons and that should not affect anything.

Have you overridden any other css? Have you set the elements to inline-block perhaps, or as btevfik touched upon, are you using any positioning on the elements? Are you overriding your button css at a later point in your css file?

There must be some other issue elsewhere causing your buttons to move around the screen.

Comment: Hi ahnkee, thanks for your reply - I've updated a jsfiddle with the complete css doc, and I suspect there is some interaction going on, but I can't for the life of me figure out what!